# executeUpdate & CURDATE()

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to do the following:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO PlayerList (nickname, uuid, firstjoined) VALUES ('" + nickName + "','" + uuid + ",' CURDATE() )");
```

But I keep getting:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'CURDATE())' at line 1
```

Can anyone explain what causes the error.

Comment: Please parameterize your queries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way can cause error syntax like you have now, and can cause [SQL Injection](http://www.journaldev.com/2489/jdbc-statement-vs-preparedstatement-sql-injection-example), so instead i suggest to use [Prepapred Statement doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), so instead to your query you can use :

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = 
    connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PlayerList (nickname, uuid, firstjoined) VALUES (?, ?, CURDATE())")) {
    ps.setString(1, nickName);
    ps.setString(2, uuid);
    int i = ps.executeUpdate();

}
```

You get this error because you miss a quote `'" + uuid + "'`

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong single quote `'` (you have after the comma but need before)

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO PlayerList
                       (nickname, uuid, firstjoined)
                        VALUES ('" + nickName + "','" + uuid + "', CURDATE() )");
```

*but you should use parameterized query avoiding string concatenation*

Answer (score 1):

`'` in wrong Place near curDate(),you can try this

```
 statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO PlayerList (nickname, uuid, firstjoined) VALUES ('" + nickName + "','" + uuid + "', CURDATE() )");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to change your statement to prepared statement otherwise you are not protected from SQL injection. Second, try to execute the function and look if it is supported by your sql database. Third, why not create the date using Java function and then pass it as param to the prepared statement.

```
Something like: java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2017-03-03");

String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
    + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
    + "(?,?,?,?)";
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setDate(4, date);
```